# T-SQL SUM manually defined values for X columns

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to `INSERT` a value into a column called `Total` for a number of hours spent throughout the week.

I have a form on a website that allows a user to input values for Mon, Tues, Weds, Thurs, Fri, Sat & Sun.

I can access the entered values via tokens for each field. IE: if I need the value for Mon, I can grab it using [Mon] and it will pull whatever number the user has entered into the column.

Using this I can build a query such as:

```
INSERT INTO MyTbl (Mon, Tues, Weds, Thurs, Fri, Sat, Sun,)
VALUES ('[Mon]', '[Tues]', '[Weds]', '[Thurs]', '[Fri]', '[Sat]', '[Sun]')
```

I'm having trouble modifing this query to `SUM` all of the day's values as my `Total` column insert value.

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTbl (Mon, Tues, Weds, Thurs, Fri, Sat, Sun, Total)
VALUES ('[Mon]', '[Tues]', '[Weds]', '[Thurs]', '[Fri]', '[Sat]', '[Sun]',    
        SUM('[Mon]', '[Tues]', '[Weds]', '[Thurs]', '[Fri]', '[Sat]', '[Sun]'))
```

Note that all columns are set to `VARCHAR` datatype in SQL Server.

Any help or examples appreciated.

IF Data looks like:

```
Mon, Tues, Weds, Thurs, Fri, Sat, Sun
1    2     3     4      5    6    7
```

I need a `Total` field that would sum all day values for in `INSERT` like:

```
Mon, Tues, Weds, Thurs, Fri, Sat, Sun, Total
1    2     3     4      5    6    7    28
```

Basically I need some query that can calculate the `Total` field in this example a value of `28` and `INSERT` that into the `Total` field in my table.

Comment: Do you have the ability to modify the definition of the table?

Comment: What is the name of your table with week days? They are in a table right?

Comment: Did you try to sum the columns with operator +? VALUES
('[Mon]','[Tues]','[Weds]','[Thurs]','[Fri]','[Sat]','[Sun]',
'[Mon]'+'[Tues]'+'[Weds]'+'[Thurs]'+'[Fri]'+'[Sat]'+'[Sun]')

Comment: RMH I did but got an error message, let me try that again, if not @TheEsisia gave me an Idea I can run an UPDATE query right after my insert to read the values for days and update the Totals after the initial insert was completed.

Comment: Always use the **most appropriate** datatype - ***why*** are the columns that should contain **numeric values** of hours worked stored as `varchar` ?!? Really doesn't make **any sense at all** (and will prevent you from "summing" them, too!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SUM()` is for aggregation over a number of rows.  You're in the scope of one single row.  To add the fields together, you just need to convert them to an `INT` and add them.

```
Insert  MyTbl
        (Mon, Tue, Weds, Thurs, Fri, Sat, Sun, Total)
Values  ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', 
            Convert(Varchar, (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7)));
```

Ideally, you should really be storing the values as their appropriate datatype (`INT` in this case).

A more ideal solution would be to create a computed column on the table, and have it be defined as the sum of the other fields:

E.g.:

```
Create Table MyTbl
(
    Mon     Int, 
    Tue     Int, 
    Weds    Int, 
    Thurs   Int, 
    Fri     Int, 
    Sat     Int, 
    Sun     Int, 
    Total   As (Mon + Tue + Weds + Thurs + Fri + Sat + Sun)
);
```

Doing it that way, you won't have to worry about inserting the total, or keeping it up-to-date.

Comment: your example at the top works, but it `INSERTS` my total as `1111111` given a sample value of `1` for each day, instead of inserting `7`

Comment: @AlexP You're adding strings - remove the quotes around the numbers or `CONVERT` it to an `INT`. (i.e. `'1' + '1' = '11'` vs `1 + 1 = 2`)

Comment: face-palm it's so obvious after someone whom knows explains it. Thank you very much this works!